# PC starts then stops, then starts normally

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply, ups

I have built a new PC very recently and everything seems to be in place. But when I switch it on all fans, including the CPU spins for just one second and stops immediately (it seems like the PC literally starts and stops), and then it starts by it own again and runs normally.

This only happens at the first time, to be clear I'm using a UPS (Uninterruptible power supply) unit. So when I switch on the UPS unit for the first time and power on the PC this occurs. Afterwards it just works as normal, I can shut down the PC and switch it on it will starts normally as expected. But as soon as I starts over, switching off the UPS and switching it on again, this occurs.

I tried resetting/clearing CMOS, putting aside every component (RAM, GPU, HDD's) and test. Did a memory test too, but nothing gives me a clue on what's wrong.

The only thing couldn't do is to connect the PC to direct A/C current rather via UPS.

So could this be a fault in motherboard, PSU or the UPS?

**PC specs:**

- PSU:- LEPA B550-MB 550W
- Motherboard:- ASRock Fatal1ty B150 Gaming K4
- UPS:- DCP 650VA UPS

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it, how old is UPS ?

Comment: Not very old, as I remember it's only 3-4 months old

Comment: …why can't you bypass the UPS?

Comment: I can. I'm keeping it as a safety measure to protect the PC internals over a power outage.

Comment: @oshadha - You can either use a different UPS or bypass your current one.  If you want help you have to rule out that the UPS you have is faulty.

Comment: Tried connecting to the direct A/C but the problem is still there. My UPS is fairly new and it's has a 650AV of capacity, more than enough for my 550W power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the BIOS with latest firmware and the issue seems to be resolved. So anyone who is having a similar issue and their PC is relatively new try updating the BIOS.